# Magento product feed in XML

Tags: product, magento-1.9, xml

I want to export product from magento in xml file. I don't know how to write a xml file using magento lib. Please assist me for this.

Comment: http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.in/2011/12/creating-all-products-xml-file-in.html or use rss feed of magento

Comment: you can download & install Magento 1.x extension for Product XML feed for Google Merchant Center: 
https://github.com/rahuldadhich/productxmlfeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to write the xml using the magento lib.
Just make it a simple string.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
//add filters if needed.
//$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); //for example.

$padd = '    '; //4 spaces for identation
$eol = "\n"; //end of line
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'.$eol;
$xml .= '<products>'.$eol;
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $xml .= $padd.'<product>'.$eol;
    $xml .= str_repeat($padd, 2).'<name>'.$product->getName().'</name>'.$eol;
    $xml .= str_repeat($padd, 2).'<description><![CDATA['.$product->getName().']]></description>'.$eol;
    $xml .= str_repeat($padd, 2).'<price><![CDATA['.$product->getFinalPrice().']]></price>'.$eol;
    //add here all the attributes you need to export
    $xml .= $padd.'</product>'.$eol;
}
$xml .= '</products>'.$eol;
//Do something with $xml - save it in a file or echo it.
```