# Exporting all products in a xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, export

I would like to export ALL of my products and their fields into an XML file. I tried [this](http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/creating-all-products-xml-file-in.html) but didn't work. I'm using Magento 1.9.

Comment: what error did you get? That link is to a very old post - it might be a version issue

Comment: No error, but I can't seem to find the exported file in my root folder

Comment: You can check below link to export products feed in XML file. - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40756/magento-product-feed-in-xml

Comment: have you checked file permissions? Usually only the owner can write to document root.

Comment: @jscar Yes, I've checked and I'm the owner.

Comment: @AshokDubariya where do I execute this? Do I save it as a php file in my root folder?